# .htaccess Rewrite Rules GET Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written an web app in php with an dispatcher, so I want to pass the controller and function via get parameters to index.php, but to get SEO URLs I want to write some rewrite rules, but I cant geht them to work.
Here an example.

URL: http://api.domain.com/v1/  here is the index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
#Das explizite Setzen der Basis-URL f�r die weiteren Manipulation.
RewriteBase /v1/

#schlie�e existierende Dateien
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Ignoriere URL's die mit .htm enden
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.htm
#es erfolgt ein Aufruf ohne trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

#api events und mods
RewriteRule    ^Login/do/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$    ?evt=Login&mod=_do&username=$1&password=$2&m=$3    [NC,L]    # Process to index

#Es wird gepr�ft, ob es sich um eine vorhandene Datei handelt.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Es wird gepr�ft, ob es sich um ein vorhandenes Verzeichnis handelt.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Verarbeite alles mit der index.php Datei.
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

I want an URL like this: http://api.domain.com/v1/Login/do/username/password/m/
But my php script dont get the Login and _do params!
What's wrong with these rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaner version of your htaccess, this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^Login/do/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?evt=Login&mod=_do&username=$1&password=$2&m=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```